# dhcpcd vs NetworkUtils.runDhcp() on Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, networking, configuration

I am modifying Android 5.0.2 on Nexus 9 to receive an USB device as a ethernet channel. When I configured to make Nexus 9 to be a host device (with RNDIS driver) and plugged my usb device to the Nexus 9, the device appeared as interface usb1 in /sys/class/net (because there's usb0 in system - I don't know why). When using NetworkUtils.runDhcp() to configure the interface, I received error message "dhcp_do_request failed : usb1 (new)" and "DHCP request error: Timed out waiting for dhcpcd to start". However, when I used dhcpcd usb1 manually, the function passed and I can retrieve the IP address.
So, why cannot I use NetworkUtils.runDhcp() to configure my interface? What is different between using runDhcp() and dhcpcd? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is you have not registered the dhcpcd service for the interface with system (this service will be called in NetworkUtils.runDhcp()). **Solution**: add following code to *init.flounder.rc* (for Nexus 9):

```
service dhcpcd_usb1 /system/bin/dhcpcd -aABDKL
    class main
    disabled
    oneshot

service iprenew_usb1 /system/bin/dhcpcd -n
   class main
   disabled
   oneshot
```